# How to get the values in all columns in datagrid?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

[I am trying to get the data name1 row to label1 and username1 to label2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyt2Y.png)

Basically, what I am trying to do is how can I get the rows data in a separate labels from row 1 to 3. In just a single click

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    iCount = iCount + 1
    Label1.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(iCount.Tostring).Cells(iCount.ToString).Value.ToString
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this `DataGridView` bound to data that we are not seeing, if so, you can go after the backing data to get it. On another note, the code above isn't looping anything and you would only get one record and then are assigning that to just one label. How are your labels named? Also, it would be a great idea to create a class that holds this data and create a `List(Of T)` of this class and do what you need with the objects.

Comment: Did you want to click anywhere in DataGridView? If you need to save all items for specific columns in the DataGridView, Combobox control is a good choice. If I have any misunderstanding, please provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

You bind the datagridview and the controls through the same bindingsource to the same datasource; create a dataset, datatable, switch to form view, open the data sources window, drag the datatable to the form, switch the mode to details and drag it again, run the app

Looks like this (click to animate if you see this as still):

[image]